# Rotate image by css, but crop it to be always same square

Tags: css

I would like to have rotate and zoom efect on pictures here
http://cpband.itvp.eu/
, but i would like to keep them croped in the same box.
like here
http://cpband.itvp.eu/test.php

trick should be in 
  overflow: hidden;
, but I am not able to figureout how to make it work.

Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Please provide your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may add the rotation to the container :

```css
.pic {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.grow img, .grow  {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
 
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
       -o-transition: all 1s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
          transition: all 1s ease;
}
.grow:hover {
  transform:rotate(15deg);
}
.grow:hover img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}


/* DEMO PURPOSE */
html {
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  }
```

```html
<div class="grow pic">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/people/9" alt="portrait">
</div>
```

or is only to the image ? *Also, transform can do both(zoom&rotate)*

```css
.pic {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.grow img, .grow  {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
 
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
       -o-transition: all 1s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
          transition: all 1s ease;
}

.grow:hover img {  
  transform:rotate(15deg) scale(1.25);
}


/* DEMO PURPOSE */
html {
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  }
```

```html
<div class="grow pic">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/people/9" alt="portrait">
</div>
```

Comment: Work like a charm! Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Html:

```
<div id="container">
<img src="picture.jpg" id="picture" />
</div>
```

Css:

```
#container{
overflow:hidden;
width:100px;
height:100px;
}
#picture{
height:300px;
width:300px;
}
```